# matlab-prettifier only shows up black text

Tags: listings, matlab

This is my preamble for my book documentclass:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings

\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{calc}


%\usepackage{bigfoot} 
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{empheq}
% Index
\usepackage{calc} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{myformula/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  %colback=ocre!10,
  colback=mygray,
  colframe=ocre,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  highlight math style={
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
    colframe=red.
    }
  }
}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{spread}[1]{%
  \advance\jot#1% indeed
  }{%
\ignorespacesafterend
}
```

When I try to put some matlab code in:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
% example of while loop using placeholders
while "\ph{condition}"
  if "\ph{something-bad-happens}"
    break
  else
    % do something useful
  end
  % do more things
end
\end{lstlisting}
```

It only shows up as black and white:

[image: black and white Matlabcode]

where as I wanted to get:

[image]

can you tell me how I can fix my tex file so that the Matlab code can show up with color??

Comment: Add `style=Matlab-editor` to the `lstlisting` environment options. Without this, the `listings` package has no idea what style to apply to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite similar to an example in the [`matlab-prettifier` package manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/matlab-prettifier).

First, we need to tell `listings` which style to apply, with `style=Matlab-editor`.

Second, if you want to use `\ph` as shorthand for the placeholders, you must do `\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder` to define the shorthand as discussed in the manual.

Third, even with the shorthand, you still have to choose and tell `listings` about a suitable escape character, so it knows when to escape from verbatim processing. Here, I've used `` escapechar=` `` as in the manual.

Here's a minimal example showing all the requirements for this code listing:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily,
  escapechar=`,
  caption={For educational purposes},
]
% example of while loop using placeholders
while `\ph{condition}`
  if `\ph{something-bad-happens}`
    break
  else
    % do something useful
  end
  % do more things
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

And the resulting output:

[image]

---

The specific fonts you selected do not provide `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` symbols, which are used internally by `matlab-prettifier` to delimit the placeholders. We can work around this by renewing the commands to use the math-mode angle brackets since the text-mode angle brackets are not provided. I do this using the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother
```

Another option would be to define `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` on your own. In that case, the code block I added above is not required.

Here's the full code using the math-mode symbols:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}

\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily,
  escapechar=`,
  caption={For educational purposes},
]
% example of while loop using placeholders
while `\ph{condition}`
  if `\ph{something-bad-happens}`
    break
  else
    % do something useful
  end
  % do more things
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Spot on! Thanks Paul; I've got nothing left to explain :) See you at TUG!

Comment: Hello, I got an error:                                                                                     ! Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textlangle not provided by
(textcomp)                font family ptm in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead.     can you tell me how to work around this?

Comment: I don't get that error; maybe your installation is not fully up to date. You can check this by adding `\listfiles` at the top of the code from my answer and typesetting. Then look near the end of the log file for the file list. Mine is here for you to compare: https://gist.github.com/pdgessler/f7167781b2763cae4cab

Comment: Hello Paul,  it works perfect with your minimal example.  However, with my original code that I published, I keep getting that error.  I am trying to incorporate your solution into a manual that I am trying to get done with all  those declarations originally given above.  Can you help me get your solution to work with the original declarations??  THANK YOU!

Comment: @Joe please see the edit; there's no need for yelling.

Comment: @PaulGessler, sorry if it appeared as I was yelling, but I wanted to humbly show my appreciation for your time and help.  Your updated solution works perfectly!

Comment: @Joe, OK, got it. The lack of emotive communication in plain text strikes again. :-) Glad it's working for you now. Cheers! :-)

Comment: How can I use this while I'm loading the code externally: `\lstinputlisting{code.m}`

Comment: @sodiumnitrate the options are just entered in a slightly different position: `\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor,<...>]{code.m}`.