# get matlab-prettifier to work in pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, matlab

in the min example below, I cannot get the file to compile as it complains that I must change my typesetting engine to xelatex or lualatex instead of plain latex or pdflatex.  In my original program, I can only compile in pdflatex because I am using koma-script.  Is it possible to get this min example working in pdflatex?

```
\documentclass[%
   ,paper=a4
   ,pagesize=auto
   ,BCOR=0.75cm
%   ,oneside
   ,DIV=10
   ,numbers=noenddot
   ,captions=heading
   ,captions=nooneline
   ,listof=totoc
   ,bibliography=totoc
   ,index=totoc
   ,headings=normal
   ,USenglish,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}

\newfontfamily{\lstconsolas}{Consolas}

\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Algorithm}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms


\begin{document}

%\lstlistoflistings

\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\lstconsolas,caption=Sample code from Matlab]{sample.m}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\lstconsolas\small,
  escapechar=`,
  caption={For educational purposes},
]
% example of while loop using placeholders
while x2 = 1 + 100 `\ph{condition}`
  if `\ph{something-bad-happens}`
    break
  else
    % do something useful
  end
  % do more things
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is how the output should appear:
[image]

Comment: What forces you using xelatex is `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `Consolas` font. Don't use them and your file will workd with pdflatex. In any case I don't understand "I can only compile in pdflatex because I am using koma-script".

Comment: @Ignasi, I wanted to change the font inside of matlab-prettiefer and this is the only way I knew how.  Is there an alternative to change the matlab-prettiefer font to be compatible with pdflatex?

Comment: What gives you the impression that KOMA-script requires pdflatex? It will work just fine with pdflatex (dvi mode and pdf mode), xelatex and lualatex.

Comment: @Ignasi, I have updated what the output should look like. I think that fontspec is needed for the \ph command to work???

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*New answer*

If you want to use `Consolas` font, you have to use `xelatex` which means to use `fontspec` but NOT `inputenc`. You can read why in [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21736/using-xelatex-instead-of-pdflatex)

`ph` command doesn't need `fontspec` as [Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248691/1952) showed to you.

`scrbook` perfectly works with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

This is what I get from your code commenting out `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages:

[image]

which as you can see uses `Consolas` font among others

[image]

*Previous answer*

A long comment. We'll see if it can be converted in answer.

This is what I get with your code commenting out `fontspec` and without any font setting in `listings`. (I've suppressed escape char around `\ph` because it didn't worked for me)

[image]

And this is what I get with the same code but adding `\usepackage{inconsolata}`  in preamble. As you can see the font used in listings changed because `inconsolata` defines a new typewriter font. Is something like this what you want?

[image]